# Update main thread from worker without a dispatcher

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, thread-safety

This have probably been asked before, but I cant find the right answer.

I have a dll that runs a pipe in it's own thread. I use that dll in a Unity project, but the messages I push to Unity end up as exception, due to I don't call them from the main thread. So I need some help implementing this right. Here's how I start the background worker:

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var client = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "kinect-pipe", PipeDirection.In);
            client.Connect();

            while (_isWorkerRunning)
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(client))
                {
                    string temp;
                    while ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        // TODO send message to Unity in main thread
                    }
                }

                if (!client.IsConnected)
                {
                    client.Connect();
                }
            }

            client.Flush();
            client.Close();
            client.Dispose();
        };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

My pipe client runs in a thread, I have a public event that fires the messages to Unity. But i need to ensure the messages is dispatched. And I am not sure how to do this the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution, where I use a shared buffer across the threads. So my pipe look like this:

```
    private void PipeClientWorker()
    {
        //Client
        var client = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "kinect-pipe", PipeDirection.In);
        client.Connect();

        while (_isWorkerRunning)
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(client))
            {
                string temp;
                while ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    // TODO figure out how to do this in the right thread
                    if (KinectHandler != null)
                    {
                        KinectHandler.BeginInvoke(temp, null, null);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!client.IsConnected)
            {
                client.Connect();
            }
        }

        client.Flush();
        client.Close();
    }
```

And I start it normally:

```
var thread = new Thread(PipeClientWorker) {Name = "Pipe Worker Thread", IsBackground = true};
thread.Start();
```

In Unity I've created a KinectController that puts the messages in a stack, and in the Update loop pops them to a single LastMessage string:

```
public string LastMessage;

private KinectReader _kinectReader;
private volatile Stack<string> _messageStack;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    _messageStack = new Stack<string>();
    LastMessage = "";

    // init Kinect Reader
    _kinectReader = new KinectReader();
    _kinectReader.StartPipeReader();
    _kinectReader.KinectHandler += _kinectReader_KinectHandler;
}

void _kinectReader_KinectHandler(string message)
{
    _messageStack.Push(message);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    // Update Last message
    while (_messageStack.Any())
    {
        LastMessage = _messageStack.Pop();
        Debug.Log(LastMessage);
    }
}

void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    Debug.Log("Stoping the pipe client");
    _kinectReader.Stop();
    Debug.Log("Qutting application");
}
```

If anyone have similar issues or have solved it different I would like to discuss the solution :)

Comment: One last thing would be to make the stack thread safe, the obvious would be to use the nice 4.0 feature BlockingCollection<>. But that's not an option here :(

Answer (score 0):

Try [Thread Ninja](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/15717). With it you can run background jobs in a coroutine style.

Comment: Ohh, that look pretty neat :)